# How about a multi layered canvas without absolute

Tags: html, canvas

Hello everyone
Im trying to create a multilayered canvas and what i came up with was something like

```
<canvas class="canv" id="fight_layer1" width="680" height="381"  style="position:relative;left:0;top:0;z-index:0">
```

I can't use the absolute it messes up the layers if im including the page on another one, is there any other way than this one, :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to place all your canvas tags inside of the DIV with absolute positioning, then they relatively position inside of it.

Also for multi layer canvas see this script (could be useful):
http://code.google.com/p/multi-layer-canvas/